# Scroll bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

So I have this modal that I would like to automatically scroll down to the chart area when you click on calculate button. I have this code:

```
  $('#budgetCalModal').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#result").offset().top
  }, 1000);
```

But it does not seem to work. I am using bootstrap 3. Any clues?

PS: It should scroll when the modal is larger than the window height obviously.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please show your html and js code in question. And best also create a bootply with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will solve your problem but here is a fiddle -http://jsfiddle.net/qe1w87ba/ that does what you want based on anchor tags within the modal window.

```
 <script>
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('.modal').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```